# MSMQ is not processing messages greater than certain size

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq

We have MSMQ with WCF QueueListener written in C#. recently we have created some services which are creating messages of size like 76970, 76969, 76938... these messages are not being processed by MSMQ but all the messages less than these size are processed fine.

Note: I dont have any limit set to my MSMQ

How can i resolve this issue?
Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Are the messages arriving on the destination Q, or not hitting the Q at all?

Comment: they are arriving at the queue but they are not being processed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestionis to enable diagnostic logging to see what is actually going on.
It could be a message size issue but logging should assist the diagnosis.

Check this out

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx

You can then examine the logs with "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\SvcTraceViewer.exe"

Post back with results if you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome - it's helped me out a few times as well. :)